# How to add external jar in grails 3.3.11?

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, jar, grails3

I have tried creating a lib folder added the jar file in the same folder. 
This what i have added in build.gradle

```
 compile fileTree(dir: './lib',include: ['*.jar'])
```

This is no lib folder by default in grails 3. I am not able to import classes from the jar file
I would like to know what the proper way of adding external jar in grails 3.

Comment: Is this specific to intellij (as in: intellij can not find the class, but the code works fine standalone)?  `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')` is how it works (I doubt your little differences matter, but you could of course try)

Comment: Thanks @cfrick  yes i think its specific to intellij.  after writing the full package name, intellij is suggesting class name.

Answer (score 0):

Shocked others haven't answered this.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
```